# Pyside Signal and Slots connect New Method

Tags: python, pyside, signals-slots

This code:

```
self.buttonOk.clicked(self.accept())
self.buttonCancel.clicked(self.reject())
```

Shows this error:

```
TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable
```

How do I connect buttonOk's clicked() signal to accept() Slot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

Firstly, you need to use the signal's `connect()` method to make the connection; and secondly, you need to pass in a *callable object* (i.e. no parens).

So your code needs to look like this:

```
self.buttonOk.clicked.connect(self.accept)
self.buttonCancel.clicked.connect(self.reject)
```

An overview of PySide's signal and slot support can be found [here](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide).